# How to make php if option is required in select?

Tags: php, html, html-select

$saat=="07:30"
I'm projecting the select an option equal to its value on the screen and the user has to choose an option from here.
There are many more options with else if. I'm just posting the IF part here to ask my question.
How to write select option is required?

```
<?php if($saat=="07:30") {echo  '<strong> <center>  <div class="select"> <select name="koltuk" id="koltuk"><option selected="selected">Seçiniz</option> <option value="vagon1">Vagon 1 &nbsp; --> 2 Koltuk Boş</option> <option value="vagon2">Vagon 2 &nbsp; --> 10 Koltuk Boş</option> <option value="vagon3">Vagon 3 &nbsp; --> 5 Koltuk Boş</option> <option value="vagon4">Vagon 4 &nbsp; --> 3 Koltuk Boş</option> <option value="vagon5">Vagon 5 &nbsp; --> 2 Koltuk Boş</option> <option value="vagon6">Vagon 6 &nbsp; --> 2 Koltuk Boş</option> <option value="vagon7">Vagon 7 &nbsp; --> 2 Koltuk Boş</option> <option value="vagon8">Vagon 8 &nbsp; --> 3 Koltuk Boş</option> </select> <div class="select-dropdown"></div> </div><br> </center> </strong>'; }

<select name="koltuk" id="koltuk" required>
```

as it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point to put the `required` in a statement separately. Just put it in the `<select>` tag

So use this code (and then amend further to suit your needs)

```
<form>
<?php 

$saat="07:30";

if($saat=="07:30") {

echo  '<select name="koltuk" id="koltuk" required>

<option selected="selected">Seçiniz</option>
<option value="vagon1">Vagon 1 &nbsp; --> 2 Koltuk Boş</option> 
<option value="vagon2">Vagon 2 &nbsp; --> 10 Koltuk Boş</option> 
<option value="vagon3">Vagon 3 &nbsp; --> 5 Koltuk Boş</option> 
<option value="vagon4">Vagon 4 &nbsp; --> 3 Koltuk Boş</option> 
<option value="vagon5">Vagon 5 &nbsp; --> 2 Koltuk Boş</option> 
<option value="vagon6">Vagon 6 &nbsp; --> 2 Koltuk Boş</option> 
<option value="vagon7">Vagon 7 &nbsp; --> 2 Koltuk Boş</option> 
<option value="vagon8">Vagon 8 &nbsp; --> 3 Koltuk Boş</option> </select> 
'; }

?>

<input type=submit>
</form>
```

You may check the following sandbox

http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/testso9oct2022.php

and

(for an initial selected value which is not blank)

http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/testso9oct2022b.php